# spring boot: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have the following class:

```
@EmbeddedId
private BookAuthorId id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId("bookIsbn")
private Book book;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("authorId")
private Author author;

@NotNull(message = "Author's index can not be null")
@Column(name = "author_index")
private Integer index;
```

}

So, basically, I try to delete a book without any author and it works, when I have some authors with a book I get:
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`books`.`books_authors`, CONSTRAINT `FKg92282id84r9l5youm7y12vpg` FOREIGN KEY (`book_isbn`) REFERENCES `books` (`isbn`))

Some ideas?

Ty

Answer (score 2):

You have to detach the entities first. You are deleting a book, but that same book is referenced in the author entity and that is why you are receiving this error.

You should write logic for removing the book from author and then to delete the book. You could check this blog post for more information https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-the-best-way-to-remove-entities-from-a-many-to-many-association/

Comment: This is what I did, I tried to delete from entity first then error comes up when he was trying to delete from book_author. The problem was I was following this tutorial: https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/, because I have a Many-to-one relationship. The problem was I couldn't use cascade because I dont use any joins, I resolved this adding  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) on Book field. Ty for help

Comment: try changing to `fetch.EAGER`. when using `lazy` it won't be able to delete via cascade since spring did not load it. when getting that exception, it means that you are trying to delete an `author` but the author has a `relation` to another table. so basically you are deleting an author and the book still stays which is impossible.